# Efficient method for generating a list of values from a column in a data frame based on common secondary columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame (df) in Python with 4 columns (ID, Status, Person, Output). Each ID is repeated 6 times and the Output is the same for each ID. For each ID, the Status will be On/Off (3 of each).

I need to generate a new column with a list of people for each unique ID/Status combination. I also need a second new column with a group ID for each unique list of people.

This is my current code which works but is very slow when working with a large data frame due to the apply(list) function. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

```
people = df.groupby(['ID','Status'])['Person'].apply(list).reset_index(name='Names_ID')
people['Group_ID'] = people['Names_ID'].rank(method='dense')
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['ID','Status'])
df = df.merge(people, on = ('ID', 'Status'))
```

Here is an example input data frame:

```
df=
ID  Status  Person  Output
0   On  John    1
0   On  Mark    1
0   On  Michael 1
0   Off Peter   1
0   Off Tim     1
0   Off Jake    1
1   On  Peter   0.5
1   On  Dennis  0.5
1   On  Jasper  0.5
1   Off John    0.5
1   Off Mark    0.5
1   Off Michael 0.5
2   On  John    2
2   On  Mark    2
2   On  Larry   2
2   Off Peter   2
2   Off Dennis  2
2   Off Jasper  2
```

The desired output is:

```
df =
ID  Status  People                Group_ID  Output
0   On  [John, Mark, Michael ]      0       1
0   Off [Peter, Tim, Jake ]         1       1
1   On  [Peter, Dennis, Jasper ]    2       0.5
1   Off [John, Mark, Michael ]      0       0.5
2   On  [John, Mark, Larry ]        3       2
2   Off [Peter, Dennis, Jasper ]    2       2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
df_out = df.groupby(['ID', 'Status'])['Person'].apply(list).reset_index()
df_out['Group_ID'] = pd.factorize(df_out['Person'].apply(tuple))[0]
df_out
```

Output:

```
   ID Status                   Person  Group_ID
0   0    Off       [Peter, Tim, Jake]         0
1   0     On    [John, Mark, Michael]         1
2   1    Off    [John, Mark, Michael]         1
3   1     On  [Peter, Dennis, Jasper]         2
4   2    Off  [Peter, Dennis, Jasper]         2
5   2     On      [John, Mark, Larry]         3
```

OR

```
df_out = df.groupby(['ID', 'Status'])['Person'].apply(', '.join).reset_index()
df_out['Group_ID'] = pd.factorize(df_out['Person'])[0]
df_out
```

Comment: So much simpler than mine. I'll have to study this one. You left out "Output" though. I didn't realize you could use .apply at the end of a groupby, particularly to a list.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_clipboard()
df
```

One method is to use `shift` twice and join the three columns into a list. Then use `groupby` to figure out the Group_ID and `merge` it back into the dataframe.

```
df['Person1'] = df['Person'].shift(-1)
df['Person2'] = df['Person'].shift(-2)
df['People'] = '[' + df['Person'] + ',' + df['Person1'] + ',' + df['Person2'] + ']'
mult_3 = []
for i in df.index:
    if i==0 or i%3 == 0:
        mult_3.append(i)
df = df.loc[df.index.isin(mult_3)].drop(['Person', 'Person1', 'Person2'], axis=1)
df_people = df.groupby('People').Status.count().reset_index().drop(['Status'], axis=1).reset_index()
df = df.merge(df_people, how='left', on='People').rename(columns={'index':'Group_ID'})
df = df[['ID', 'Status', 'People', 'Group_ID', 'Output']]
df
```

Answer (score 0):

**Python 3.7.6 and Pandas 1.0.3:**  The bottleneck here are probably the `apply` calls.

```
people = df.groupby(['ID','Status', "Output"])['Person'].apply(list).reset_index(name = 'People')
people['Group_ID'] = people["People"].apply(str).astype('category').cat.codes
```

**Output:**

```
  ID Status Output                   People  Group_ID
0  0    Off      1       [Peter, Tim, Jake]         3
1  0     On      1    [John, Mark, Michael]         1
2  1    Off    0.5    [John, Mark, Michael]         1
3  1     On    0.5  [Peter, Dennis, Jasper]         2
4  2    Off      2  [Peter, Dennis, Jasper]         2
5  2     On      2      [John, Mark, Larry]         0
```